# WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped in GlassFish 3.1.2.2

Tags: jsf, cdi, glassfish-3, omnifaces, view-scope

I have a Multi-Maven-Project with some EJBs and one WAR (in one EAR). I need at least one bean to be @Named and @ViewScoped. With all beans @SessionScoped, everything works fine.

If I change one bean to @org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped, I get the following error during page-load:

```
2014-09-11T09:50:31.576+0200|SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/user/page.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /user/page.xhtml @14,193 rendered="#{not myBean.editing}": org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:413)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:297)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:309)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderAll(PartialViewContextImpl.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:287)
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:981)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:390)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at com.bmw.tmtool.filter.HtmlHeadsetFilter.doFilter(HtmlHeadsetFilter.java:24)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:664)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:77)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:87)
at com.bmw.tmtool.controller.org$jboss$weld$bean-TMToolWeb_war-ManagedBean-class_com$bmw$tmtool$controller$DesignStepController_$$_WeldClientProxy.isEditing(org$jboss$weld$bean-TMToolWeb_war-ManagedBean-class_com$bmw$tmtool$controller$DesignStepController_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:59)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:55)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
... 68 more

2014-09-11T09:50:31.576+0200|WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:630)
at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.startCDATA(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:172)
at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startError(PartialResponseWriter.java:342)
at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startError(OmniPartialViewContext.java:376)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:156)
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:200)
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:123)
at com.bmw.tmtool.filter.ViewExpiredExceptionExceptionHandler.handle(ViewExpiredExceptionExceptionHandler.java:60)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at com.bmw.tmtool.filter.HtmlHeadsetFilter.doFilter(HtmlHeadsetFilter.java:24)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I know that Glassfish 3.1.2.2 does not support multiple WARs when using Omnifaces.

My Bean:

```
...
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Named(value="myBean")
@ViewScoped
public class myBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -521973607671355077L;
private boolean editing; //+getter/setter
@Inject
SomeSessionScoped bean;
@Inject
transient Logger logger;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "This Method is never called");
}

// Lots of stuff
}
```

My WEB-pom:

```
    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cupertino</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    ...
```

Am I missing something or is there a workaround?